# itertools.groupby can not group django queryset by a foreignkey correctly

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Supposed I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then, I want to select all posts and group them by category:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Post.objects.all().select_related('category').order_by('category')
posts_group = groupby(qs, key=attrgetter('category'))
```

However, posts_group doesn't contain the expected data.

For example, I hava two posts in database, the belong to different category. The query does select all category but only one post display in last category group.

Comment: `groupby` works sequentially though an iterable. if you want to collect all of the same keys together, you need to sort yourself.

Comment: The query already order the posts by category.

Comment: You're going to have to create a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: You neglected to show how you *use* the `groupby` iterable (and a *lot* of folks get this wrong, so it's really important; your described misbehavior sounds a lot like you tried to `list`ify the whole thing which is the *wrong* thing to do). Please include a [MCVE] that includes that code.

Comment: apply `values()` first.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835484/4257237

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
def groub_posts_by_cat():
    groups = {}
    categories = Post.objects.values('category')
    for cat in categories:
        groups.update({
            cat.name: Post.objects.filter(category__pk=cat.pk)
        })
    return groups
```

Also here is an [excellent](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html) article on how to perform group_by annotations.

Comment: This solution would hit the database very iteration, not a good idea.

Comment: This solution will hit database only once in the  line `categories = Post.objects.values('category')` values in the `groups` dict are querysets that has not been evaluated yet.

Comment: Which is still bad! you're better off pulling all Posts and group them in memory rather than querying for every category!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
posts = Posts.objects.all()
posts_groupped = {post.category: list() for post in posts}

for post in posts:
    posts_groupped[post.category].append(post)
```

But your `Category` model should have defined hashing:

```
class Category(models.Model)
    ...
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.title)  # title or any other Category attribute with uniqueness for avoiding hash collisions
```