# Django, how to group models by date?

Tags: python, django

Lets say that I have `MyModel` that has `created_at` and `name` fields. `created_at` is DateTime.

Lets say that I have the following model objects:

```
<id: 1, name: A, created_at: 04.06.2020T17:49>
<id: 2, name: B, created_at: 04.06.2020T18:49>
<id: 3, name: C, created_at: 05.06.2020T20:00>
<id: 4, name: D, created_at: 06.06.2020T19:20>
<id: 5, name: E, created_at: 06.06.2020T13:29>
<id: 6, name: F, created_at: 06.06.2020T12:55>
```

I want to make query that will return to me these models in this order:

```
[
    04.06.2020: [<id: 1, name: A, created_at: 04.06.2020T17:49>, <id: 2, name: B, created_at: 04.06.2020T18:49>],
    05.06.2020: [<id: 3, name: C, created_at: 05.06.2020T20:00>]
    06.06.2020: [<id: 4, name: D, created_at: 06.06.2020T19:20>, <id: 5, name: E, created_at: 06.06.2020T13:29>, <id: 6, name: F, created_at: 06.06.2020T12:55>]
]
```

I want to group all models by `created_at` field, but only using `Date` part of `DateTime` field. I know that I can make that kind of result just by using python loops, but are there any Django ORM way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please post your models related with the queries?

Comment: @gutsytechster This is just example model with `name` and `created_at` datetime field

Comment: See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828916/django-rest-framework-regroup-queryset-by-a-category for a similar question.

Comment: @simlist There are not proper answer that I'm looking for. The most upvoted answer users iterators which I know, I want Django Query way to get that kind of data

Comment: the datetime to date conversion here is kind of a red herring, that part is pretty easy with annotations and the `Trunc` operator.  what you can't do though is get results in this format with the ORM. the ORM mirrors SQL and there isn't a SQL analogue to this as SQL returns tabular data, and this isn't tabular. Any extension accomplishing this would be not doing it with SQL / would be masking iterations, which it seems is not what you want. If performance loss from iterating is a concern, SQL might not be the tool for this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ORM itself cannot return list of models but you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this purpose assuming you order the dataset at the database level first.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

queryset = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    created_at_date=TruncDate('created_at'),
).order_by('created_at')
groupedset = groupby(queryset, attrgetter('created_at_date'))
```

You'll then be able able to iterate over `groupedset` using

```py
for date, objects in groupedset:
    ...
```

Comment: I think it will be  `created_at__date` and not `created_at_date`

Comment: @hardik24 no, `created_at_date` is the alias chosen when doing `annotate`.

Comment: my fault. I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code:

```
samples = MyModel.objects.all()
result = {}
for sample in samples:
    date_string = sample.created_at.strftime("%m.%d.%Y")
    if date_string in result:
        result[date_string].append(sample)
    else:
        result[date_string] = [sample]
```

It will return output like following:

```
{
'06.07.2020': [<Sample: MyModel object (1)>],
'05.07.2020': [<Sample: MyModel object (2)>, <Sample: MyModel object (3)>]
}
```

Basically, what it does it it first fetches all the rows and then group it at python level into a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is currently not completely possible, at least to my knowledge (without some really deep modifications within the Django ORM).

What you can do, however, is doing date conversions and aggregations within the database:

> *This example assumes your database supports the `to_char` function.*

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
qs.annotate(
  created_at_date=models.Func(
    models.F('created_at'),
    models.Value("'dd.MM.yyyy'"),
    function='to_char',
  )
).values('created_at_date').aggregate(
    # do required aggregations like Count or Sum
)
```

[edit] some fixes + as bryan60 correctly pointed out, you can also use `Trunc`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
    created_at_trunc=Trunc('created_at', 'day', output_field=models.DateTimeField())
).values('created_at_trunc')
```

Comment: you're close, but you're missing this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc

Comment: @bryan60 Sorry, I overwrote an edit with my edit - was it yours?. Trunc is also an option, yes, but if you wish to convert the date to a different locale format you still need to use to_char :)

Comment: i did not edit, but i also don't see the part of the qusstion where OP says anything about converting the date to a different locale? he just says he wants to group by the date portion of a DateTime field?

Comment: @bryan60 true, if he doesn't need a custom format trunc will do as well, I just assumed it was a different locale due to the german-looking format :)

Answer (score -2):

Not quite understanding but if you have the database created under models.py then you can create a meta class that shows ordering

```
Class myModel(models.Model):
    #fields...

     Class Meta:
         ordering = ('-created_at')
```