# Django ORM how to get raw values grouped by a field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

I have a model which is like so:

```
class CPUReading(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    reading = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am trying to get a result which looks like the following:

```
{
    "host 1": [
        {
            "created": DateTimeField(...),
            "value": 20
        },
        {
            "created": DateTimeField(...),
            "value": 40
        },
        ... 
    ],
    "host 2": [
        {
            "created": DateTimeField(...),
            "value": 19
        },
        {
            "created": DateTimeField(...),
            "value": 10
        },
        ... 
    ]
}
```

I need it grouped by host and ordered by `created`.

I have tried a bunch of stuff including using `values()` and `annotate()` in order to create a `GROUP BY` statement, but I think I must be missing something because in order to use `GROUP BY` it seems I need to use some aggregation function which I don't really want to do. I need the actual values of the `reading` field grouped by the host field and ordered by the created field.

This is more-or-less how any charting library needs the data.

I know I can make it happen with either python code or with raw sql queries, but I'd much prefer to use the django ORM, unless it explicitly disallows this sort of query.

Comment: After messing around a bit, I don't think there's anything in the ORM for this, you will need to use a raw query if you want this done in the database. I think you might have an easier time with this if your database was normalized, i.e. you had a `Host` model.

Comment: I've added an answer based on this, in case it works for you, but if it doesn't, it might be useful to others.

Comment: use [itertools.groupby and operator.itemgetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828916/django-rest-framework-regroup-queryset-by-a-category/49835484#49835484)

Comment: Can you show the SQL query that you think would create this data structure? GROUP BY will only return you one row of the readings per result row...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's nothing in the ORM that makes this easy. If you want to do it in the ORM without raw queries, and if you're willing and able to change your data structure, you can solve this mostly in the ORM, with Python code kept to a minimum:

```py
class Host(models.Model):
    pass

class CPUReading(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(Host, related_name="readings", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reading = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

With this you can use two queries with fairly clean code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)
hosts = Host.objects.prefetch_related("readings")
for host in hosts:
    for reading in host.readings.all():
        results[host.id].append(
            {"created": reading.created, "value": reading.reading}
        )
```

Or you can do it a little more efficiently with one query and a single loop:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)
readings = CPUReading.objects.select_related("host")
for reading in readings:
    results[reading.host.id].append(
        {"created": reading.created, "value": reading.reading}
    )
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer I'll get. I'm really just frustrated about this one aspect of the django orm. I'll give you the bounty unless someone gives me an answer using the database in the next day or so.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using PostgreSQL you can use a combination of `array_agg` and `json_object` to achieve what you're after.

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregation import ArrayAgg
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField, JSONField
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.expressions import Func, Value

class JSONObject(Func):
    function = 'json_object'
    output_field = JSONField()

    def __init__(self, **fields):
        fields, expressions = zip(*fields.items())
        super().__init__(
            Value(fields, output_field=ArrayField(CharField())),
            Func(*expressions, template='array[%(expressions)s]'),
        )

readings = dict(CPUReading.objects.values_list(
    'host',
    ArrayAgg(
        JSONObject(
            created_at='created_at',
            value='value',
        ),
        ordering='created_at',
    ),      
))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay close to the Django ORM, you just need to remember this doesn't return a queryset but a dictionary and is evaluated on the fly, so don't use this in declarative scope. However, the interface is similar to QuerySet.values() and has the additional requirement that it needs to be sorted first.

```py
class PlotQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def grouped_values(self, key_field, *fields, **expressions):
        if key_field not in fields:
            fields += (key_field,)
        values = self.values(*fields, **expressions)
        data = {}
        for key, gen in itertools.groupby(values, lambda x: x.pop(key_field)):
            data[key] = list(gen)

        return data


PlotManager = models.Manager.from_queryset(PlotQuerySet, class_name='PlotManager')

class CpuReading(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reading = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = PlotManager()
```

Example:

```py
CpuReading.objects.order_by(
    'host', 'created_at'
).grouped_values(
    'host', 'created_at', 'reading'
)                                                                                                  
Out[10]: 
{'a': [{'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 16, 45, 23, 215005, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'reading': 0},
  {'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 16, 45, 23, 223080, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'reading': 1},
  {'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 16, 45, 23, 230218, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'reading': 2},
  ...],
 'b': [{'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 16, 45, 23, 241476, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'reading': 0},
  {'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 16, 45, 23, 242015, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'reading': 1},
  {'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 16, 45, 23, 242537, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'reading': 2},
   ...]}
```